# Editing a DOM/HTML Element

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I was trying to find and answer to my question but I've found none.
I expect the solution to be simple, I just think I'm making some syntax errors.

What I want to achieve: I want to add a new `"<dd>"` element to my `"<dl>"` through a JavaScript.

The `<dd>` element would have an `<a>` element inside,  like:

```
"<dd><a href =...></a></dd>"
```

The link to  would need to be taken from a form.

Here's the code. I don't really know how to finish it - just starting with JavaScript.

```
<dl id="dl">
<dt>Menu</dt>
<dd><a href="index.html">Home</a></dd>
<dd><a href="galeria.html">Galeria</a></dd>
<dd><a href="canvas.html">Canvas</a></dd>
<dd><a href="ankieta.html">Ankieta</a></dd>
<dd><a href="query.html">JQuery</a></dd>
<dd><a href="mobilki.html">Mobilne</a></dd>
</dl>
<form method="post" id="formularz" onsubmit="myFunction3()">
<p><input type="text" name="link" id="link" value="Tutaj wpisz swój link"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="tytul" id="tytul" value="Tytuł linku"</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Potwierdź"></p>
</form>
<script>
function myfunction3(){
var link  = document.getElementById("link");
var tytul = document.getElementById("tytul");
var dd = document.createElement("dd");
var dl = document.getElementById("dl");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = link;
a.text = tytul;
dd.add(a);
dl.add(dd);

}   
</script>
```

Thanks for help in advance!

I've editted  my script.

Comment: Do you know about single or double quotes?

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference right now. I know I can use both, the code isn't really finished. I have no idea how to modify <dl> to add a new <dd> element with a <a> within...
How do the quotes make any difference?

Comment: You know you can use both? You must use either single or double, currently there are no quotes at all in the JS code.

Comment: Text must always be surrounded by single or double quotes in javascript. HTML is text. If javascript examples had been seen, this would be obvious.

Comment: Oohh you mean in like document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = " ..... ";?
I tried using double quotes there, didn't do much good.
I am going try something else with createElement method hmm

Comment: I editted my script now, any good?
a notice: still doesn't work in my test site :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <dl id="dl">
    <dt>Menu</dt>
    <dd><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </dd>
    <dd><a href="galeria.html">Galeria</a>
    </dd>
    <dd><a href="canvas.html">Canvas</a>
    </dd>
    <dd><a href="ankieta.html">Ankieta</a>
    </dd>
    <dd><a href="query.html">JQuery</a>
    </dd>
    <dd><a href="mobilki.html">Mobilne</a>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <form id="formularz">
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" value="Tutaj wpisz swój link" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="tytul" id="tytul" value="Tytuł linku" />
    <br/>
    <button name='submit'>Potwierdź</button>
    <br/>
  </form>
  <script>
    function $(sel) {
      return document.querySelector(sel);
    }
    $('#formularz').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $('#link'),
        tytul = $('#tytul'),
        el = document.createElement('dd');
      el.innerHTML = '<a href="' + link.value + '">' + tytul.value + '</a>';
      $('#dl').appendChild(el);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This page adds a link at the end of `#dl` when the form is submitted.
Also, you may want to take a look at this great free book on Javascript to help you with some of the basics: [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do.
Thanks a bunch! :3
I will check the free book today. It will be usefull.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myfunction3(){
var link  = document.getElementById("link");
var tytul = document.getElementById("tytul");
document.getElementById("dl").innerHTML = '<dt>Menu</dt>\
<dd><a href="index.html">Home</a></dd>\
<dd><a href="galeria.html">Galeria</a></dd>\
<dd><a href="canvas.html">Canvas</a></dd>\
<dd><a href="ankieta.html">Ankieta</a></dd>\
<dd><a href="query.html">JQuery</a></dd>\
<dd><a href="mobilki.html">Mobilne</a></dd>\
<dd>NEW ELEMENT HERE, where <a href="link"> tytul (title)</a></dd>';         
}   
</script>
```